# Transactions in Azure Data Factory & SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have a solution, in which an `SSIS` package is deployed on `Azure`. The package is being executed via `Data Factory (V2)` using `Execute SSIS Package` task in a `pipeline`.

I have a `sequence container` within the package, in which I would like to enable the transaction for (all child components inside the container much succeed, otherwise to roll-back).

I changed the transaction option to `Required`, however after triggering the `pipeline` I got this errors (from SSIS Logs):

> Error: 0xC001402C at MyPackage: The SSIS Runtime has failed to enlist the OLE DB connection in a distributed transaction with error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".

> Error: 0xC0202009 at MyPackage: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred.
> Error code: 0x80070057.
> Error: 0xC020801C at MyDataFlow, Missing Codes [69]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "My Connection" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

> Error: 0xC004701A at MyDataFlow, SSIS.Pipeline: Missing Codes failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Is there any configuration that I miss on the `SSIS` package, or on the `Data Factory (V2)` side ?

(My `Azure SQL Database` is a standard deployment, with `General Purpose` service tier)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see you have also [posted this in Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/275230/transactions-in-azure-data-factory-amp-ssis.html) which is answered by @MartinJaffer-MSFT. Copying here for easy reference:

> We took a look in our records and found where someone else got a
> similar error.  They were trying to  migrate integration processes
> from on-prem to the cloud.
>
> SQL PaaS doesn’t support distributed transactions the same way as
> on-prem.
>
> For leveraging Azure SQL PaaS (as per your current architecture), you
> would need to develop a custom C# OR .Net app that handles the
> workflow:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview#installation-and-migration
>
> For leveraging SQL Managed Instance, you would need to user SQL Trust
> Groups, which are in preview:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview#transactions-across-multiple-servers-for-azure-sql-managed-instance
> Both SQL MI and SQL DB have distributed transactions limitations:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-transactions-overview#limitations